# What is the overhead of using shipped production server in docker?

Tags: django, apache, docker

I'm new to containerization and I'm facing some inner questions.

I saw some examples of docker images which are shipping apache2/wgsi with the django application. Is this the best way to procede ? Each container should have their own production server ? I guess this creates a lot of overhead on the host system.

Is there a way to use the host system production server to host different images ?